# Relieve topology tension on planes and borders

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, modifiers, normals, topology

I was prototyping a steel shield and everything was good until I had to carve holes in it. It was a simple task, but I've noticed something that I ever wonder how to solve it. The topology around those holes shows some glitchs and tension problems that I've never modelled.

So, how I've come to this (and most important) how can I solve this volume rendering problem?

You can see in the images below what I'm talking about. The yellow lines are for reference of what looks wrong. The only modifier I'm using is **Mirror** and for better render results I've set the normals to 60º in **Auto Smooth**.

[image]

Your help is really appreciated.

[image: topology tension 1]
[image: topology tension 2]
[image: topology tension 3]

Comment: From what I know, this is more than likely a result of poor topology. Generally, whenever I make cuts into a mesh, whether it be circular or oval shaped, I try to use something made out of 8 verts. You're completely correcting in saying that they are 'tension points', and I'd hazard a guess that it is due to the tris and the smaller faces located around the edges of the cuts. I'll provide an answer later on the day, should hopefully resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I know that I have some tris and ngons problems, but sometimes I find really hard to not use them or trying to properly make it on quads. I'll wait for a solution hopefully. Thanks again.

Comment: Creating fully quad based meshes isn't something, as far as I am concerned, that can be explicitly taught. Personally, I found that more and more modelling practice eventually allowed me to solve most topology problems. But I will do my best to outline the key problems with your mesh in my answer.